# CSS Missing Pixels, Size of full width block != Width of page

Tags: html, css

Anyone else facing this issue? When you sum up the width of all objects (including border,padding,margin) spanning the width of a page or simply a full width block, it does not add up to the width of the window; width of the window being the width indicated by Chrome Dev Tools.

It always seems to be 17 or 18 pixels short, i.e. content is n-17 px wide on a n px window.

Comment: Have you set `body{margin:0px;}` sounds like the issue. Default margins are ~ 8px... meaning 16.

Comment: Could you show us an example?

Comment: Is the difference the width of the scrollbar?

Comment: @acfrancis That sounds probable. The Chrome scrollbar is ~18px. Both Chrome/Safari take the scrollbar into consideration when calculating the width, whereas IE/FF doesn't.